# Warning: The domain 'www.yukohorita.click' does not resolve, please fix its DNS entries to remove it.' to HTTPS on AWS Lightsail WordPress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I was following the instruction of AWS to enable HTTPS on my AWS lightsail WordPress instance. I created the domain 'yukohorita.click' on AWS Route53 and set up S3 bucket for both 'yukohorita.click' and 'www.yukohorita.click', however the bitnami console is still showing the warning:

[Warning: The domain 'www.yukohorita.click' does not resolve, please fix its DNS entries to remove it.'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1a70.png)

I have no clue how to fix this anymore...

--- update ---
I created domain on AWS Route53 and followed [this instruction](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-quick-start-guide-wordpress).
I also connected the domain and DNS zones and Static IP to my instance. Inside Domain I set up DNS records with 'www.yukohorita.click' as subdomain. My zone is Virginia (us-east-1), so it may take a lot of time to get the domain works...? (I just got the domain today)

--- update ---

[DNS settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o48nk.png)

--- update ---

[Route53 Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuIpw.png)
[Route53 DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTFQ6.png)

---update -----
I changed DNS setting to:
[Latest DNS Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHPNI.png)
However it doesn't work.

--- update on 9:00 PM JST ---
I solved the issue by setting A record in DNS setting in Route 53. Thank you for help everyone.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us how you have configured the domain. Also, please provide a link to "the instruction of AWS" that you are using.

Comment: I updated the question. Please take a look

Comment: Your domain name is not resolving to an IP address. Please show us your DNS Configuration from the Networking tab. (eg a screenshot)

Comment: Your DNS settings look good, but it still isn't creating the A-Record that is necessary to resolve the domain. Can you show us the configuration in Route 53 for `yukohorita.click`?

Comment: I avoid personal info and IDs, but please take a look at updated images

Answer (score 0):

This might be because your domain has an invalid IP setting meaning it when you try going onto the website or enable HTTPS it can't as there is no IP connected. Check your DNS Settings and try again.

Comment: Thanks Leon. I connected IP and set subdomain in DNS report but still it does not work. I registered domain this morning so it may be taking a long time to take effect, I will update here if the domain gets active.

Comment: Your domain doesn't resolve meaning the A Record in your domain settings is invalid or is null. You would need to fix this to be able to use the domain. If you have everything set out correctly, you will need to check all the settings for the domain to make sure you didn't mistype anything.